# How do I start a Windows GUI App with a GitHub Self-Hosted Action Runner?

Tags: python, github, yaml, workflow, github-actions

My action is running fine, but is not starting any GUI application.

Here is the action's code:

```
name: Python package

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Run with python
      run: |
       .\BasementRenovator.py
```

Is there anything specific about running GUI applications via self-hosted action runners?

Comment: Use Task Manager to check processes for all users and you probably can find those GUI applications. Due to Windows session isolation, your user account can only see applications in its logon session, but not applications in other users' sessions (the GitHub action agent runs in just another session if you installed it as a service).

Comment: It ran when I opened up run.cmd in the action runner's folder on my desktop prior to running the GitHub action. After running, the python script popped up for a second but then quit out before it had finished. Any ideas why? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JaedenHillesheim - have you got any work around or solution to achieve this? I am looking for this...